Pixel Shift when using Fourier Downsampling
I am working on a Super-Resolution network, and want to try to use Fourier downsampling, different from the normally used bicubic downsampling as it relates to MRI imaging. I have tried using this post. When I'm comparing the Fourier downsampling with the bicubic it seems like pixel shift occurs (going from corner to corner), and it feels like something is going wrong. I would not suspect these systemic differences (see image bellow).
I have translated the code to python, using Pytorch libraries, as it has to run on GPU's:
import torch
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import torch.nn.functional as F


# Load the image
image_path = r"My/Image.jpg"
image = Image.open(image_path)

# Define a transformation to convert the image to grayscale tensor
transform = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Grayscale(),  # Convert to grayscale
    transforms.ToTensor()    # Convert to tensor])

def bicubic_downsampling(input_tensor, scaling_factor = 2):
    # Get input tensor dimensions
    batch, depth, height, width = input_tensor.shape
    

    # Calculate the new spatial dimensions after downsampling
    new_height = int(np.floor(height * 1/scaling_factor))
    new_width = int(np.floor(width * 1/scaling_factor))


    # Use torch.nn.functional.interpolate for bicubic downsampling
    lr_imgs = F.interpolate(input_tensor, size=(new_height, new_width), mode='bicubic', align_corners=False)

    return lr_imgs


def fourier_downsampling_2D_old(input_tensor, scaling_factor = 2):

    _ , _, height , width = input_tensor.shape  #B x C x H x W 

    # select center pixels
    center_x = height//2
    center_y = width//2
    
    
    crop_dim_x = int(center_x//scaling_factor)
    crop_dim_y = int(center_y//scaling_factor)

    fimage = torch.fft.fftshift(torch.fft.fft2(input_tensor))

    fft_crop = fimage[:,:,(center_x-crop_dim_x):(center_x+crop_dim_x),(center_y-crop_dim_y):(center_y+crop_dim_y)]

    
    tensor_downsampled = torch.real(torch.fft.ifft2(torch.fft.ifftshift(fft_crop/(scaling_factor**2))))
    

    return tensor_downsampled


image = transform(image)

lr_fourier = fourier_downsampling_2D_old(image.unsqueeze(1))
lr_bicubic = bicubic_downsampling(image.unsqueeze(1))

plt.figure(figsize=(10,15))
plt.imshow(lr_bicubic.squeeze()-lr_img.squeeze(),cmap='RdBu')

Here is an example of the difference image when subtracting the Fourier downsampled image to the bicubic one.

The phenomena is systemic using my code, and happens regardless of image. I have tried to shift the image, but the error explodes, and i have looked at the 2D Cross Correlation and it also indicates they have the best alignment. It looks like only high frequency components are effected (witch makes sense), but why is it effected in seemingly only one direction? The direction surely has something to do with the combination of oscillations along the x and y axis, as it moves across the image from corner to corner.
When i compare the HR image to both donwsampling methods magnifying them to the same size, you can see the shift using Fourier, whereas the bicubic is downsampled "in-place". Hope it makes sense and that someone can explain how this happens.

Did you standard debugging procedures? Start with a single pixel, then do a straight line,    diagonal line, square, etc. If already a single pixel is shifted, that should be easy to track down.

My domain is more in machine learning, so I'm not sure exactly what the standard procedure is. I have tried what you said and I'm seeing the same thing. One diagonal has less error than the other and is downsampled "in-place". You can even see the slow oscillation creating "zones" with more error than others. Maybe it's just the sharp edges in the images that can be modulated without significant overshoot/undershoot when decomposing it into Fourier space? Im a bit new in here, should i answer my own questions with the findings using the debugging procedures, so you can see the images?

Surely the two downsampled images are of slightly different sizes?

It looks like Torch interpolation doesn’t low-pass filter the image, meaning it will cause aliasing when scaling down. Be careful when using that function!

They are the exact same size. I have a feeling that this may have something to do with aliasing of the image when downsampling using the fourier method. A lowpass gausian filter can be used before downsampling. That what im looking at now.

@CrisLuengo You came ahead of me there. Do you know of any approximation of how strong the filter should be given different images?

The Fourier method has built-in low-pass filtering. There's no aliasing there. Aliasing will happen in the bicubic interpolation method. Anyway, if the two results are of the same size, this is coincidence. The Fourier method forces the output to be odd in size, the other one doesn't. Since the scaling factor is 2, you should compare the Fourier method with image[:,:,::2,::2], which is just downsampling by a factor 2. F.interpolate() likely does something weird with coordinates.
